# Including a Link to an Old Question in a New Question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, linked-questions

If I have already asked an old question, and it's was not answered or didn't gain enough attention, or I need to include the information of that question to my new question, I would want to add a link of that question to my new question.

For example:

> Before I was having a problem with the performance of an http server which I stated already in **here**(a link). But I am afraid this leads to a new problem which is...

Is this legal here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking about a few distinct situations:

> I have already asked an old question, and it's was not answered or didn't gain enough attention.

You should not include a link to a previous question solely to attract attention to it.  Instead, you should use a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) and/or edit your question to make your problem more clear.

> I need to include the information of that question to my new question

That depends on what the information is.  Each question should contain all the information needed to answer it, at least at a basic level.  However, linking to an old question to provide context for a bigger picture can be useful because a project-level context helps ward off [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

> Is this legal here?

Yes, if your questions fall under the second "context" kind of supplemental information.

---

> Before I was having a problem with the performance of an http server which I stated already in here(a link). But I am afraid this leads to a new problem which is...

My gut reaction is that this is an appropriate place to include the context link to your previous question.  It sounds like your previous problem was solved, so its details are less important.  But since the details *might* still be relevant, a context link is a good compromise to allow people to retain the big picture view.  As long as you new question is on-topic and clear on its own, the link should be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

> Before I was having a problem with the performance of an http server which I stated already in **here** (a link). But I am afraid this leads to a new problem which is...

I don't think this is a very good structure for a question, because it requires visitors to follow the link to understand what you're asking. The new question should be able to stand on its own as an on-topic question for Stack Overflow, so in this case you would want to give enough detail about the prior performance problem and the way you're addressing it that readers will understand what's going on (and therefore hopefully be able to help you with your new question). A link to the old question could then be provided for context.

Note that you shouldn't post the exact same question a second time if your question hasn't received enough attention to bump it, as [it will be closed as a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7054/253560).